# How to combine containers in a flexbox layout?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a simple flexbox layout like this:

```css
html, body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
background:grey;
}

.container {
display:flex;
flex-direction:row;
}

.image1, .image2, .image3, .image4, .image5, .image6 {
padding:10px;
}

img {
  max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image1">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x400/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="image2">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x400/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="image3">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x400/000/fff">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="image4">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x400/000/fff">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="image5">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x400/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="image6">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x400/000/fff">
  </div>
</div>
```

I am currently doing it with 3 seperate flex containers, I am trying to combine everything in to 1.

Am I able to do this with flexbox or would CSS grid be more appropriate?

Comment: Do you want it to look as it does in three containers? but with just one?

Answer (score 2):

> Am I able to do this with flexbox

Yes, using [flex-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap) property and **wrap** value, which will force items to wrap onto multiple lines.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  background: grey;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.image {
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.third {
  width: 33.333%;
}

.half {
  width: 50%;
}

.full {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image third">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x400/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="image third">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x400/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="image third">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x400/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="image full">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x400/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="image half">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x400/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="image half">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x400/000/fff">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

You could make it even shorter, using [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) instead of `width`.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  background: grey;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.image {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.image.full {
  flex: none;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x400/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x400/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x400/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="image full">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x400/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x400/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x400/000/fff">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The layout (with a single container) is relatively easy and simple using CSS Grid.

Use Grid's [**line-based placement**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Line-based_Placement_with_CSS_Grid) techniques to position grid items and create grid areas.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.image1, .image2, .image3 {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.image4 {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  justify-self: center; /* optional */
}

.image5, .image6 {
  grid-column: span 3;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image1">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x400/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="image2">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x400/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="image3">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x400/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="image4">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x400/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="image5">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x400/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="image6">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x400/000/fff">
  </div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/epajdkcy/)